# How make it work the session lifetime and remember me in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, session-timeout, remember-me

I want to have a timeout for the session.. ie 5 minutes. But I also want to have a remember me functionaliy with a timeout of 8 hours.

So I set the session timeout in the config.yml with this:

```
session: 
    cookie_lifetime: 300
```

And then I set the remember me timeout in the security.yml with this:

```
firewalls:
    main:            
        remember_me:
            key: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 28800
            path: /
            domain: ~
```

So, if I stay working within 5 minutes and then I log out, everything goes right. But, if I stay inactive for more than 5 minutes (session timeout) and then I log out, I am automatically authenticated with the remember me cookie. Therefore, if I want to logout, I have to click twice in the Logout link.

How should I do to make them work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, this took some time to track down. :-p

Quick answer: Due to line 92 of [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/46b1b5bd60432ba07bde2732a2310a5e76f94174) commit, logout handlers aren't called (and thus, the REMEMBERME cookie isn't removed) unless there's a token in the securityContext (i.e. the user is logged in).

Longer answer: [`AbstractRememberMeServices`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blame/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/AbstractRememberMeServices.php)'s `cancelCookie` method handles the removal of the REMEMBERME token. [`RememberMeFactory`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blame/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/RememberMeFactory.php) makes sure an implementation of this abstract class is registered with the `LogoutListener` (through some convoluted service lookups involving one of the `security.authentication.rememberme.services.*` services).

`LogoutListener` (one of `Firewall`'s listeners) is supposed to iterate through all its handlers (that implement `LogoutHandlerInterface`), calling their `logout` method. You're probably using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`, whose service id is `security.authentication.rememberme.services.persistent` and whose `logout` method calls the `cancelCookie` method mentioned above, thus supposedly removing the REMEMBERME cookie.

But due to the what I explained above, it is never called for users who aren't logged in (due to the session having expired). Instead, the logoutSuccessHandler redirects you, and in the following request the remaining REMEMBERME cookie kicks into action.

---

I'm not sure whether this should be considered a bug (unintended side-effect of the commit) or not. Perhaps one of us should [submit it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bugs.html) and see what the devs make of it?

:-)